# why does the setstate callback function need to be an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

take this scenario

```
this.setState({ number: newNumber}, () => console.log(number))
```

and then this one:

```
this.setState({ number: newNumber}, console.log(number))
```

the first one (with the arrow) correctly logs the new state, the second (without the arrow) seems to console.log it one step behind.

why does the arrow function cause it to be correct in the setState callback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because, the second parameter inside `setState` [is a callback function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). But this is not a callback:

```
console.log(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the first answer, you need a callback function. `console.log()` is not a callback function if you don't wrap it inside a function.

**the second (without the arrow) seems to console.log it one step behind.**

Instead of being a callback, `console.log()` is executed immediately, logs the current value of `number` variable and passes its return value as the callback argument.

You call `console.log(number)` at

`this.setState({ number: newNumber}, console.log(number))`

and passes undefined as a callback. Since console.log() returns undefined. Such that `this.setState` becomes

`this.setState({number: newNumber}, undefined);`

`this.setState()` might have some sort of flag to not execute a callback function in cases where the callback parameter is not supplied (undefined is the same as not being supplied in terms of parameters), which explains why it's not throwing an error at `undefined()`.

Comment: ok yeh that all makes sense but does it specifically need to be an arrow function? or only if im calling `this` inside?

Comment: Not sure, I do not use React. Try `function(){ console.log(); }`. Won't take 2 minutes